# How can i rewrite type checks of object props in Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying put my head around how rewrite the following TS code using Ramda:

```
const uniqueIdentifierRegEx = /.*id.*|.*name.*|.*key.*/i;
const uniqueIdentifierPropTypes = ['string', 'number', 'bigint'];

const findUniqueProp = (obj: any) => Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(prop => uniqueIdentifierPropTypes.includes(typeof obj[prop]))
    .find(prop => uniqueIdentifierRegEx.test(prop));
```

I ended up with something like this, but it does not really work:

```
const data = {a:1, name: 'name', nameFn: () => {}};
const uniqueIdentifierRegEx = /.*id.*|.*name.*|.*key.*/i;
const uniqueIdentifierPropTypes = ['string', 'number', 'bigint'];

const filterPred = curry((obj, prop_, types) => includes(type(prop(prop_, obj)), types));
const findProd = curry((prop_, regEx) => regEx.test(prop))

const findUniqueProp = (obj, types, regEx) =>
   pipe(
     keys,
     filter(filterPred(types)),
     find(findProd(regEx))
   )(obj)

findUniqueProp(data, uniqueIdentifierPropTypes, uniqueIdentifierRegEx)
```

Potentially, [pickBy](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pickBy) can be used to filter out props... but Im lost. Please help to connect the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform an object properties by key and value, it's often easiest to convert the object to an array of `[key, value]` pairs via `R.toPairs`, transform the pairs (using `R.filter` in this case), and then convert back to an object using `R.fromPairs`.

To filter the pairs, I'm using `R.where` to check the key (index 0 in the pair), and the value (index 1 in the pair) by wrapping the RegExp, and the array of permitted types in functions.

Note: `R.type` returns the types in pascal case - `String`, `Number`, and `BigInt`.

```js
const { test, pipe, type, flip, includes, toPairs, filter, where, fromPairs } = R

const uniqueIdentifierRegEx = test(/.*id.*|.*name.*|.*key.*/i) // test if string matches regexp
const uniqueIdentifierPropTypes = pipe(type, flip(includes)(['String', 'Number', 'BigInt'])) // test if the type of the value is in the array

const fn = pipe(
  toPairs, // convert to [key, value] pairs
  filter(where([ // filter and use where to check the key (0) and the value (1)
    uniqueIdentifierRegEx,
    uniqueIdentifierPropTypes
  ])),
  fromPairs // convert back to object
)

const data = {a: 1, name: 'name', nameFn: () => {}}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, mate! Looks awesome, it is not so readable with ramda though. No way I figure out on my own.

Comment: You are welcome :) See update to R.where (changed to array).

Comment: I see, yea that's much better!